# REGEX for only 'GO' on a line

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to create a Regex in C# that will match on the word GO (ignoring case) and only where GO is the first and only word on a line (whitespace after GO is acceptable)

So in the following the bolded text is what would be matched:

> This is a test of GO
>
> **GO** (followed by whitespace)
>
> Not a go
>
> **Go** (no whitespace after Go)
>
> Not Good

Comment: What is wrong with a good old `string.Equals`?

Comment: The sarcasm provides no value to the discussion.  @BrianKE, I think the many would judge that a Regex is overkill here.  If you have the whole line in a String, like so: `line.TrimEnd().ToLower().Equals("go")` will tell you whether the line meets your criteria.

Comment: The reason for this is we have a library method that executes a single SQL script.  Some of our command scripts have multiple steps separated by a 'go'.  In order to process each step, we divide the command script on the 'go' and execute each piece individually.  the problem was that someone had a comment with 'go' in the text and what we had (\bgo\b) did not handle this scenario.

Comment: Not sure why this is on hold.  The question is a specific question that is not asking for discussion or a best way to do something.  Additionally, a straight forward answer was provided by Holger.

Comment: @BrianKE - I vtc'ed based on the fact that it is too broad. but the close reason given even states "Instead, describe the problem and *what has been done so far to solve it.*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. Perhaps you will change the options.

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^go\s*$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
        foreach(Match match in regex.Matches(input))
        {
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Won't match on Go however

Comment: Wouldn't it? There's a `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` in there

Comment: @Yorye - Doh, you're right. That would work.

Answer (score 1):

```
        string trimmed = textToSearch.TrimEnd();

        if (int.Equals(trimmed.Length, 2) && string.Equals(trimmed, "GO", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            //found the GO
        }
```

Regex is faster but, this will do the trick nicely

Comment: I highly doubt regex is faster than this

Comment: Sorry @Sayse - meant to say I believe regex will be faster if comparing multiple strings, though I'm not entirely sure!

Comment: Don't know what is faster. But you have to split a multiline string to lines first.

Comment: @HolgerThiemann Ah well, I've up-voted yours but mine may server as some inspiration at least..

Comment: I'd be more inclined to upvote this but [I don't believe answering bad questions should be encouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288176/is-showing-effort-needed)

Comment: Ok. Checked it out of curiosity. Your solution even with a split operation to split the lines seems to be faster. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex r = new Regex("^[G|g][O|o][\\s]+$");
```

Rudimentary I know, but it works.